# Double quotes(escape character) inside String(format: ) in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

\ is not working inside String(format:) for escaping character.

How to put Double quotes(escape character) inside String(format: ) in swift?

Example

```
let timeString = String(format: "https://stackoverflow.com/character=\"inside\"")
```

I need to pass url parameter without double quotes inside String(format:) so I need to escape the double quotes inside

I get stackoverflow.com/character="inside" I need stackoverflow.com/character=inside

I input with quotes as 
String(format: 'https://stackoverflow.com/character="inside"') 
but while passing to url i should pass it without quotes as
String(format: 'https://stackoverflow.com/character=inside
because in url it shows as
https://stackoverflow.com/character="inside"

Comment: Escaping is when you want the double quotes to not end the string and instead be part of it. And that works fine. Can you show what you tried, what you are getting for it and what you are expecting to get?

Comment: For example I get https://stackoverflow.com/character="inside"          I need     
              https://stackoverflow.com/character=inside

Comment: From your example, you can just write what you need instead. Show the actual code you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
let timeString = String(format: "https://stackoverflow.com/character=\"inside\"").replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
```

This will output as:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/character=inside
```

Replace the occurrences of " with nothing.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use string interpolation. You can flexibly pass integer, string, double etc

```
let timeString = String(format: "https://stackoverflow.com/character=\(inside)")
```

[Refer to: String Interpolation in swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
let timeString = String(format: "https://stackoverflow.com/character=inside")
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I input with quotes as String(format: 'https://stackoverflow.com/character="inside"') but while passing i should pass it without quotes as                                                                      
    String(format: 'https://stackoverflow.com/character=inside     because in url it shows as           https://stackoverflow.com/character="inside"